# 'g++' is not recognized in Windows 11

Tags: windows, g++

I am getting this "'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." error in Sublime Text 3 even after checking the path several times. I am using Windows 11. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Maybe you didn't restart your computer since you changed the PATH (installed GCC)? [yes there are other ways to propagate the change but restarting is the easiest.]

Comment: If this isn't the case, download Process Monitor, configure it with a filter for `Path` `includes` `g++` and watch what paths are tried (or not tried) when Sublime Text attempts to execute `g++`. This will likely give you a clue. You can also configure it to filter for `Operation` `begins with` `Process` and then look at the environment of the spawned `cmd.exe` process.

Answer (score 1):

Type "edit environment variable for your account" in start menu and press enter
Environment variable window appears
Now,click on path, then on edit
[image]
Edit enviroment variable window appears
and click on new[image]
Now add the path and finally click on OK. Relaunch the command line window. It will work.